# Import content from another text file in a current text file at specific lines in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

Here is my problem:

**Text 1**

```
alliance of (123456789)
alliance of (shhgafstys)
alliance of (aseqwerty)
.....
```

**Text 2**

```
htp://123.235.235.002
htp://125.126.214.008
htp://129.220.119.189
.....
```

So is there a way to add every n line from my initial *Text 1*, content from a second *Text 2* file in order line 1, line 2, line 3 etc?

**Combined Text**

```
alliance of (123456789)
htp://123.235.235.002
alliance of (shhgafstys)
htp://125.126.214.008
alliance of (aseqwerty)
htp://129.220.119.189
.....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I'm assuming that `alliance of` and `htp`(?) lines counts are equal.*

---

### Macro way

1. Save `Text 1` file as `Combined Text`.
2. Bookmark all `alliance of` lines (`Search` > `Bookmark` > `Invert bookmarks` or other way) - ensure that you have bookmarked only `alliance of` lines.
3. Paste `Text 2` file content before `Text 1` file content.
4. Ensure that you have an empty line at file end - might be required when using `Run macro to end of file` main menu entry.
5. Start a macro recording <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+r</kbd>.

   - Go to file begin <kbd>Ctrl+Home</kbd>
   - Cut first `htp` line <kbd>Shift+Down</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+x</kbd>
   - Go to next (first one) bookmark <kbd>F2</kbd>
   - Remove bookmark <kbd>Ctrl+F2</kbd>
   - Paste `htp` line <kbd>Down</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+v</kbd>
6. Stop macro recording <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+r</kbd>.

Now you should have a working macro. You can check it by playing it <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+p</kbd> few times. If something goes wrong you can undo <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd> and try to record working macro again.

7. If macro is recorded correctly run it to the end of file `Macro` -> `Run a macro multiple times...`. **Remember about empty line at the file end!**

### Spreadsheet way

1. Paste `alliance of` lines to first spreadsheet column.
2. Paste `htp`lines to second spreadsheet column.
3. Save file as `CSV`.
4. Open `CSV` file in Notepad++.
5. Replace `CSV` separators (`;` or `,`) with new line characters `\n` in `Extended` `Search mode`.